# Как кнопки, сделать такими?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Как сделать с кнопками, подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, размер кнопок увеличил, а вот вставить слова: Рассказать, Поделиться, Рекомендовать, не знаю, как?

Это стандартные кнопки Яндекс. Поделиться (блок). Помогите пожалуйста, а лучше кодом)), чтобы скопировать и вставить.

Comment: **Алексей** Здравствуйте! Вам стоит в вопрос добавить свой вариант кода, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться. Пока я минус вопросу поставлю, как отредактируете, уберу. Всего вам **Алексей** доброго!

Answer (score 2):

Можно так.

```css
li.ya-share2__item.ya-share2__item_service_vkontakte span.ya-share2__badge:after {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  content: 'Рассказать';
}

li.ya-share2__item.ya-share2__item_service_facebook span.ya-share2__badge:after {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  content: 'Поделиться';
}

li.ya-share2__item.ya-share2__item_service_odnoklassniki span.ya-share2__badge:after {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  content: 'Рекомендовать';
}
```

```html
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"></div>
```

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать, за что минус поставили. В ответе ровно то, о чем просил ТС.